# Pandas check if IP address is in subnet

Tags: python, pandas, ip-address

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
src             dest         count
10.10.10.10     10.20.20.20  26
192.162.122.10  10.20.20.21  30
104.20.21.23    10.20.20.22  21
10.10.10.11     10.20.20.23  25
172.16.10.10    10.20.20.24  30
10.10.10.12     10.20.20.25  45
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe from the existing dataframe if src lies in subnet 10.10.0.0/16

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
tables2_df=tables_df[tables_df['src'].isin(ipaddress.ip_network('10.10.0.0/16'))]
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Is your column a string... I guess you'll want `tables_df.src.apply(ipaddress.ip_address).isin(...)` so the comparison works? However, that's just a guess... since you haven't included what the actual error message is or elaborated on what "doesn't seem to work" means...

Comment: @JonClements That worked, thanks!
However it does appear to be rather slow, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Well, you are converting a column to a type that can be checked against a network - so I don't imagine it'd be terribly quick - but I can't think of any obvious ways to speed it up.